# Passing string parameters into function from one component to another in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to find a way to pass parameters along with state, from one component to another in ReactJs.

So my code os something like this:

```
class Component_1 extends React.Component{

 constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      initialState: false
    }
  }

  changeState(){
   this.setState({
     initialState: !this.state.initialState
   })
  }

  render(){
   return(
    <Component_2 blockName={this.changeState.bind(this)} />
   )
  }
}

class Component_2 extends React.Component{
 return(){
  render(
   <ul>
    <li className="lists">
     <div className="blocks" div_name={"about"} onClick={this.props.blockName.bind(this)}>
     //some more elements
     </div>
    </li>
    <li className="lists">
     <div className="blocks" div_name={"contact"} onClick={this.props.blockName.bind(this)}>
     //some more elements
     </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
  )
 }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is this: On click of the div element i.e "blocks", in "Component_2", I want to pass both the state and the "div_name" property from Component_2 to Component_1 into the "changeState()" function of "Component_1".

I am able to get the state but not sure how I can pass the property value i.e the "div_name" from "Component_2" to "Component_1". Is there any way to access child's props value from parent?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<div className="blocks" div_name={"about"} onClick={this.props.blockName.bind(this)}>
```

to

```
<div className="blocks" data-name="about" onClick={({target: {dataset: {name}}}) => this.props.blockName(this.state, name)}>
```

and it'll send state as first argument and string `"about"` as second argument for blockName function.

Then in your `Component_1` change

```
changeState(){
    this.setState({
        initialState: !this.state.initialState
    })
}
```

to

```
changeState(stateOfComponent2, theText) {
    // Do whatever needs to be done with stateOfComponent2 and theText variables.
    this.setState({
        initialState: !this.state.initialState
    })
}
```

But consider that I'm just answering your question which is "how to do these things?" but the way you're doing it is not the best way. Probably you need to redesign your components. I suggest you spend some time to learn best practices for your purpose.

Comment: How would i output the string parameter in Component_1? So i am passing this "about" from my component_2 and what it displayed in my Component_1. So currently the statement is: `<Component_2 blockName={this.changeState.bind(this)} />` so would there be any change in this? Since i want the string received in Component_1 onclick of "Component_2"

Comment: So if the above functn were like: `changeState(outputValue){
   this.setState({
     initialState: !this.state.initialState
   }) console.log("output value is: "+outputValue)
  }` How would i be able to achieve this?

Comment: Also, instead of passing the string "about" is there a way to pass a variable in which this string is stored?

Comment: @Amisha64 I edited the answer to address your concerns.